# No intellisense for strongly typed model in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, intellisense

Ok, since a couple of week, I lost intellisense on the model in my views.

I'm pretty sure it's not a code problem because it works for other developer on the same project.

Suppose this class :

```
namespace Project.UI.ViewModels
{
   public class TestViewModel
   {
      public int PropertyA { get; set; }

      public string PropertyB { get; set; }
   }
}
```

And this view :

```
@model Project.UI.ViewModels.TestViewModel

<div>
   @Model.PropertyA
</div>
```

When I type `@Model.` in my view, I would expect intellisense to show me `PropertyA` and `PropertyB`. By nothing happens.

However, if I type `@Html.` I *do* have the list of method for HtmlHelper.

If I type `@Model.Foo`, resharper offers me to create `Foo` property on `TestViewModel`.

I guess there is some kind of Visual Studio module that is not working properly to handle intellisense in razor views, but I can't see what.

I work with **Visual Studio 2013**, **MVC5**, **Resharper 8.2**.

**Edit**

I have this behavior since a couple of months. So I *did* closed and reopened the project, closed and reopened Visual Studio, and rebooted my computer a lot of times since.

I was not worried with that since because I was not doing a lot of UI...

I'm not *sure*, but I think it is like that since I installed VS2013. I'm sure it was working with VS2012.

Comment: Is this a web application (project) and, if so, have you tried rebuilding your project?

Comment: @Ryan : yes to both questions.

Comment: I have had this problem before. In addition to @Rupinder answer, try closing/re-opening the project and if that doesn't work try using the scaffolding to auto generate a new view as a test.

Comment: I deleted my view and recreated it and intellisense started working on Model and @Html. However, now it's not working on my iterated object in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

Same error also present with VS2017.
Deleting component model cache seems to help. Close Visual Studio, go to folder

> C:\Users\your.name.here\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\version.goes.here\ComponentModelCache

and delete files in that folder. After that restart VS and it should also prompt to fix the "Inconsistent line endings" as per @Grzesiek's answer and the component model files are recreated when VS restarts. After that everything should work again.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in VS 2015 too. When you make drastic changes to the model, the Razor intellisense may still remember the old model.

```
@model MyForm.Models.SomeModelIChangedAround
```

Restarting VS 2015 fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this issue before, and the solution was fixing "Inconsistent line endings".

Copy-pasting parts of code from other sources may cause it, and if Visual won't point that out, then the best solution would probably be to retype content of the file in a new file.

Answer (score 0):

go to tools and then modify intellisense settings in options for needed laguage under text editor option

Comment: I already checked this. Intellisence _does_ works, it's just for the `Model` that it is broken.

Comment: do you remember any changes to visual studio which you have made like installing new things for it after which intellisense stopped working. may be that could be culprit

Comment: @Rupinder Chahal, did you a find a solution? My view show the model as dynamic even though I have the (at)model viewModel at the top. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am using VB.Net MVC5 and had this problem.  Turns out the directive in VB is `@ModelType`.  The `@model` directive is for C#.